# How to replace the values from the array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following array, I want to replace names to capitals. I tried map but that creates a new array of names. Is there any other method to do this.

```
var newArr = [ {name: "ash", age: 10, address: "newhomw"},
               {name: "Jo", age: 20, address: "gloom"}
             ]
```

Comment: `newArr.map(obj => ...)` where `...` is where you are going to manipulate the passed object `obj`, which is an element of the source array. You can alter the name property of an object by doing `obj.name = ...` And last thing: to turn string to upper case, you can call `.toUpperCase()` on a string object.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: If you want to alter the array, use forEach instead of map

Comment: Cleanest one: newArr.forEach((e) => {e.name = e.name.toUpperCase()});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use forEach

```
newArr.forEach(item => item.name = item.name.toUpperCase())
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an easy one.

Answer (score 0):

- use map if you want a new array
- use forEach if you are ok with modifying the existing array

Capitalise:

```js
let arr = [ 
  {name: "ash", age: 10, address: "newhomw"},
  {name: "jo", age: 20, address: "gloom"}
];
             
arr.forEach(item => { let name = item.name; item.name = name.slice(0,1).toUpperCase()+name.slice(1)});

console.log(arr);
```

UpperCase:

```js
let arr = [ 
  {name: "ash", age: 10, address: "newhomw"},
  {name: "jo", age: 20, address: "gloom"}
];
             
arr.forEach(item => item.name = item.name.toUpperCase());

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.forEach` :

```
newArr.forEach( (item, i, self) => self[i]["name"] = item.name.toUpperCase());
```

Using `Array.map` :

```
newArr = newArr.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {name: item.name.toUpperCase()}));
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `arr.forEach(item => item.name = item.name.toUpperCase());`

Comment: @mplungjan to understand and learn possible parameters ```forEach``` takes.